# Qt std::runtime_error equivalent

Tags: c++, qt, exception

Does Qt have a class equivalent to `std::runtime_error` (like `QString` is equivalent to `std::string`)?

Specifically, `std::runtime_error` holds a string describing the error, so you can just do:

```
throw std::runtime_error("my error description");
```

Comment: Why? `std::runtime_error` is always there. Qt doesn't implement equivalents of many standard library things because standard library would be bad. It does so for historical reasons as it was started before most of them were standardized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, Qt doesn't use exceptions (other than QtConcurrent::Exception for throwing and catching exceptions across threads.) Just use the standard C++ exception classes.

Comment: Can it be used the same way - i.e. `throw QtConcurrent::Exception("string");`

Comment: @satuon No. If you want to implement error messages, you'll need to subclass it and implement that yourself.

Comment: Not strictly true, some newer modules outside qtbase use exceptions. There's no generic QException or some such though in the API.